# helm update selectif template file (specific service & deployment yaml file)

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-helm

In my Microservices architecture i have a helm chart by microservice used to deploy it in Kubernetes, every microservice/chart has 3 pods

```
-helm
  - chart.yaml
  - values.yaml
  - templates
    - nginx-deployment.yaml
    - nginx-service.yaml
    - php-deployment.yaml
    - php-service.yaml
    - varnish-deployment.yaml
    - varnish-service.yaml
```

when i execute

```
helm upgrade --install my-analyzer ./helm/
```

the three pod are updated (So far it's fine)
My question :
how can i do with Helm to upgrade only one or two pods a time and not touch the others
exemple : upgrade nginx and varnish but keep php without changes

Comment: I would guess if no changes were made to let's say php manifest file then helm upgrade will not modify the state of any running pods

Comment: my deployment change the docker image name set by a Jenkins build Number 
so the pod modification is automatic

Comment: I think you need to change/modify the pipeline logic, If there isn't any change in the source code or services (for example upgrade the varnish version) why would you/CI change the docker image tags?

Comment: I would just skip building images for code that doesn't change in J-pipeline. If you want to avoid updating part of the a chart, override changed parameters of the chart (in your case images) by `--set` option in command line.  E.g.: `--set php-image=currently-deployed-image-name`  https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#customizing-the-chart-before-installing

Answer (score 1):

I've missunderstood your question. I have edited my answer.

Unfortunately it is impossible to achieve that in [Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/).

Each time you are upgrading `Helm` its creating new `Release`. Its going throught all YAMLs in `Chart` and deploying everything what have inside based on [this order](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/9ad53aac42165a5fadc6c87be0dea6b115f93090/pkg/tiller/kind_sorter.go#L29).

You can use `IF` statement in YAML if you want to execlude something from deploying. Example can be found on [Github](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/postgresql/README.md).

In [this](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/postgresql/templates/svc-read.yaml) service, on the beginning of the YAML you can see if statement in 1st line:

```
{{- if .Values.replication.enabled }}
```

However if 1st `Release` will contain specific deployments in templates and 2nd will not, Helm will delete objects from 1st `release` which were not included in 2nd.

Only thing what you could change is use `helm upgrade` with `--set` flag which can overwrite some default values.

You can also consider advse from Alireza Davoodi or VAS about change pipeline logic.

Comment: when i tried {{- if .Values.phpDeploy }} in the begenning of the deployement yaml file  and  the values.yaml with phpDeploy: true i execute helm upgrade . --set phpDeploy=false then Helm remove dthe php deployement and pods if exist

Comment: What version of Helm did you use?

Comment: helm version v2.14.3